# Is it possible to edit face detection jquery?

Tags: jquery, face-detection

i would like to ask you..

i found a link that provide a code to use face detection on image using jquery,

here is the link...

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/11/face-detection-using-jquery.html

my question is, is it possible to edit the script to detect a wheels on car image..

for the detail i'll provide an image to you..

http://www.kiosban.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/bha.png

anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The project you are looking at uses software called [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

The specific plugin you are using is data that has been generated by *training* from real data (faces) already identified.  The software uses samples to *learn* how to find a subject of interest.

In your case, wheels may be easy to train for.  It depends on how many different angles you want them to be recognized at.  Wheels straight on (from the side), looking like O, should be relatively easy for OpenCV to identify.  You wouldn't necessarily even have to use something as complex as **haar training** like the face detection does.  You could likely get away with some other edge detection which identifies circular shapes (of a dark color) on a similar plane.

Comment: how to do that? can you explain me how to do that?